# OpenVPN: correct way to use a relative path in an OVPN file

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am attempting to connect to a service using OpenVPN.

There are a number of configuration files (`.OVPN`) that share a single certificate (`ca.crt`); all are located in the same directory.  Canada.ovpn, for example:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ca.#########.com 443
resolv-retry 5
nobind
fast-io
float
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
route-delay 5 30
script-security 3 system
ping-restart 0
mute-replay-warnings
verb 3
```

When I attempt to connect:

```
sudo openvpn --config ./configs/canada.ovpn --auth-user-pass ./credentials.txt
```

I get an error that reads:

> Options error: --ca fails with 'ca.crt': No such file or directory
>   Options error: Please correct these errors. Use --help for more
>   information.

It seems that `openvpn` is having difficultly with the relative path.  I changed the relevant line to `ca ./ca.crt`, but that resulted in the same error.

Configuration files that have an in-line certificate work as expected.

What is the correct way to use a relative path to a certificate in an `.OVPN` file?

Comment: Where is the file `ca.crt` located? One directory up from where `canada.ovpn` is, as the config and command line suggests?

Comment: It is also located in the `configs` directory (i.e. with the `*.ovpn` files).

Comment: Ok, good to have that confirmed. Then I believe my answer should have you covered both in terms of what is the current problem and how `--cd` is likely the road to sanity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that the referenced file does not exist in the current working directory.

Is your intention to reference a file that is also in the same directory as the config (`.ovpn`) file? If so, based on your command line, it does not appear that these files are actually in `./` but rather in `configs/`.

As a better approach, I believe you may want to use the [`--cd` option](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) to have `openvpn` change working directories before opening any files.

Comment: That worked.  Needed to move the credentials file (cred.txt) to the same directory.  Working command: `sudo openvpn --cd /etc/certificates/configs --config canada.ovpn --auth-user-pass ./cred.txt`